# Run mvn test,can find the test class, but shows Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Tags: java, maven, junit

the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

my project structrue
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO1at.png

this is part of one of my test class:

all the package import:

```
package rockets.mining;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import rockets.dataaccess.DAO;
import rockets.dataaccess.neo4j.Neo4jDAO;
import rockets.model.Launch;
import rockets.model.LaunchServiceProvider;
import rockets.model.Rocket;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static rockets.mining.MapMethod.frequencyOfListElements;
import static rockets.mining.MapMethod.sortMapByValues;
import static rockets.model.Launch.LaunchOutcome.FAILED;
import static rockets.model.Launch.LaunchOutcome.SUCCESSFUL;
```

my test class:

```
public class RocketMinerUnitTest {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RocketMinerUnitTest.class);

    private DAO dao;
    private RocketMiner miner;
    private List<Rocket> rockets;
    private List<LaunchServiceProvider> lsps;
    private List<Launch> launches;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        dao = mock(Neo4jDAO.class);
        miner = new RocketMiner(dao);
        rockets = Lists.newArrayList();

        lsps = Arrays.asList(
                new LaunchServiceProvider("ULA", 1990, "USA"),
                new LaunchServiceProvider("SpaceX", 2002, "USA"),
                new LaunchServiceProvider("ESA", 1975, "Europe ")
        );

        // index of lsp of each rocket
        int[] lspIndex = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
        // 5 rockets
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            rockets.add(new Rocket("rocket_" + i, "USA", lsps.get(lspIndex[i])));
        }
        // month of each launch
        int[] months = new int[]{1, 6, 4, 3, 4, 11, 6, 5, 12, 5};

        // index of rocket of each launch
        int[] rocketIndex = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3};

        //outcome of rocket of each launch
        Launch.LaunchOutcome[] outcome=new Launch.LaunchOutcome[]{SUCCESSFUL,SUCCESSFUL,FAILED,SUCCESSFUL,FAILED,SUCCESSFUL,FAILED,SUCCESSFUL,FAILED,FAILED};

        // 10 launches
        launches = IntStream.range(0, 10).mapToObj(i -> {
            logger.info("create " + i + " launch in month: " + months[i]);
            Launch l = new Launch();
            l.setLaunchDate(LocalDate.of(2017, months[i], 1));
            l.setLaunchVehicle(rockets.get(rocketIndex[i]));
            l.setPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.random()*(1000000)+60000000));
            l.setLaunchSite("VAFB");
            l.setLaunchOutcome(outcome[i]);
            l.setOrbit("LEO");
            spy(l);
            return l;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    /*
     * author Ziang Shen
     * */
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = {1, 2, 3})
    public void shouldReturnTopMostLaunchedRockets(int k){
        when(dao.loadAll(Launch.class)).thenReturn(launches);
        List<Rocket> sortedRockets=new ArrayList<Rocket>();
        for(Launch launch:launches)
        {
            if(launch.getLaunchOutcome()==SUCCESSFUL)
                sortedRockets.add(launch.getLaunchVehicle());
        }
        Map<Rocket,Integer> map=frequencyOfListElements(sortedRockets);
        sortedRockets.clear();
        map=sortMapByValues(map);
        for(Rocket rocket:map.keySet())
            sortedRockets.add(rocket);
        List<Rocket> launchedRockets=miner.mostLaunchedRockets(k);
        assertEquals(k,launchedRockets.size());
        assertEquals(sortedRockets.subList(0,k),launchedRockets);
    }
```

this is the mvn test result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running rockets.dataaccess.neo4j.Neo4jDAOUnitTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in rockets.dataaccess.neo4j.Neo4jDAOUnitTest
Running rockets.mining.RocketMinerUnitTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in rockets.mining.RocketMinerUnitTest
Running rockets.model.LaunchServiceProviderUnitTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in rockets.model.LaunchServiceProviderUnitTest
Running rockets.model.RocketUnitTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in rockets.model.RocketUnitTest
Running rockets.model.UserUnitTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in rockets.model.UserUnitTest

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.396 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-06T09:50:45+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this result shows that it did find all the unittest class,however,the result is run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0.

Comment: Most likely you don't have the right annotations. You didn't show your complete code.

Comment: now I upload the completed one of my unittest class,what is the right annotations?

Answer (score 5):

You are using JUnit 5 (Jupiter) and an old version of maven-surefire-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

1. Use the latest: as of 2021-08-05, either 2.22.2, either 3.0.0-M5.
2. You can remove the `configuration` part, since `*Test` is included by default.

See [JUnit 5 documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven):

> Starting with **version 2.22.0**, Maven Surefire and Maven Failsafe
> provide native support for executing tests on the JUnit Platform. The
> pom.xml file in the junit5-jupiter-starter-maven project demonstrates
> how to use the Maven Surefire plugin and can serve as a starting point
> for configuring your Maven build.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```